# Django settings outside of project

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that uses SQLAlchemy to use some legacy ORM objects. This application also hits up an ldap server for user authentication. I was getting sick of moving from development to production servers for both ldap and the database. I was hoping to create a IS_DEVELOPMENT variable in the settings.py. One problem I am running into is that the ORM modules are not in the Django project.

I know django.conf does a great job of parsing that settings file and making those settings available to you throughout your application.  What I can not figure out is how to make those same settings available to myself outside of that app.

Anyone done this one before?

Comment: DEBUG is usually set to False in production.  You could check for DEBUG is True in your development environment and add your own values for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Standalone Django Scripts"](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/)

Comment: Thanks, looking now, I did try the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE once, but probably messed that one up.